# Use string concatenation in conditional statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, conditional-statements, string-concatenation

I have written 5 var names.

```
var row1 = "1";
var row2 = "2";
var row3 = "3";
var row4 = "4";
var row5 = "5";
```

I need to do a condition within every var inside a loop. But I cannot get it to work. Below is the script I used.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    if (row.concat(i) == "") {
        console.log("."+row.concat(i));
    } else {
        console.log(false);
    }
}
```

Note: Each var can contain dynamic values, so I am just getting those that are blanks.
Appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

```js
var row1 = "1";
var row2 = "2";
var row3 = "3";
var row4 = "4";
var row5 = "5";
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
  if (row.concat(i) == "") {
    console.log("." + row.concat(i));
  } else {
    console.log(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use individual variables, use an array.

Comment: E.g.: `var rows = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]; for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) { if (rows[i] == "") { console.log("." + row[i]); } else { console.log(false); } }` But the linked question's answers talk about dynamic variable names if you **really** need to do that. (You almost never really do.)

Comment: You can access the variable values in loop like this: `window['row'+i]`